# How to execute ESRI Leaflet map in PHP as a windows service

Tags: php, windows, service, esri-leaflet

I have Created an Esri-leaflet map using (Esri-leaflet CDN from Esri leaflet GitHub repository) which plots markers and also written code to get the image exported with markers on page load and is saved as PHP file, Now I want to run this file as a service so that the code keeps running in the background and keep generating images even after a system reboot. I have tried to execute with cmd but only the code is shown up but not executed.

If anyone can find a solution much-appreciated Thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards

G Revanth Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP Extension Win32Service available here: https://pecl.php.net/package/win32service.

Extension documentation : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php

A library is available to help you to use the extension : https://packagist.org/packages/win32service/service-library

A Symfony Bundle is also available : https://packagist.org/packages/win32service/win32servicebundle